# Measure execution time of threads in multiple-thread environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, multithreading

Is it possible in Ruby/Rails to measure the actual execution time of a single thread, within a multi-threaded environment?

I am creating up to 10 threads at once, and I am currently calculating the elapsed time for each thread, but since the multiple threads are sharing the processor(s), there will be gaps in as they share resources. So my time is going to be more than actual.

```
@urls.each do |url|
  Thread.new do
    time = Time.now
    request = http.get(url)
    response_time = Time.now - time
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Your results might depend on what Ruby implementation you're using. If you stick with MRI for example, you'll have only green threads, meaning they are basically simulated threads, no real system threads involved. That also means you can't make usage of multiple processors. So which Ruby are you using ?

Comment: Oh and you should use Benchmark to measure your performances, not basica arithmetic with Time.now :) http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wycats](http://yehudakatz.com/) has made a cool gem called [ruby-prof](http://rubydoc.info/github/wycats/ruby-prof) that should help you. It supports profiling multiple threads simultaneously, including process time, cpu time, and wall time.

Comment: That's a great lead. I'll check it out now.

Comment: Any thoughts on using this to measure process time in production since I am actually using it in production, not just to measure processes for improvement? I see a mention of ruby-prof doubling actual process time.

Comment: I'm not sure how specific they get, but NewRelic has a really monitoring service that starts out free. It's been awhile since I've used it, but I really liked it, and that was a while ago, I'm sure it's matured since then. It did not seem to adversely impact performance, and it's free to try. Maybe worth giving it a shot? https://newrelic.com/

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about you, but a lot of our production apps are crazy fast, and would not be measurably impacted by doubling many of the areas. Or perhaps if you have a particularly slow area you are trying to narrow down, maybe it would be worth the temporary slowdown, even a few minutes of analysis could point you toward your problem.

Comment: Or, you could attempt to replicate your production environment, and simulate load... I'm guessing relative numbers are more relevant than absolute timings...

Comment: Actually, my usage is actually to measure time--I'm assessing response times of web services--and its being done with threads. And the issue is trying to narrow down times affected by delays imposed by other threads. The problem I see now is that process time, may not include actual HTTP response time, which is what I really want to measure. Anyway, your answer is definitely spot on.